# Not returning matched regex character in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Trying to teach myself perl and regexes.

Would like to know how to return the "+" if a user enters Smith+ in lastname. As in, "User entered invalid character, specifically "+" in the last name field."

```
unless (    $string1 =~ m/^[\w\.\s\-]+$/        &&  #last name must contain only words, periods, spaces and dashes
            $string2 =~ m/^[\w\.\s\-\@]+$/      &&  #email must contain only words, periods, spaces and dashes and at symbols
            $string3 eq "Find Order"            &&  #submit button field must match Find Order
            $string1 ne ''                      &&  #last name can't be empty
            $string2 ne ''                          #email can't be empty
       )
       {
       print "$& $1 $` $'";    #these don't return anything and it makes me sad
       &error;
       }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to explicitly test for bad characters and/or conditions

```
if ( $string1 eq '' ) { 
    say "Name can't be empty";
    error();
}
elsif ( my @bad_namechars = $string1 =~ /([^\w.\s-])/g ) { 
    say "Character(s) \"@bad_chars\" aren't expected in a name";
    error();
}
elsif ( $string2 eq '' ) { ... }
elsif ( my @bad_emailchars =~ /([^\w.\s-\@])/g ) { ... } # etc
```

If you'd rather detect all errors, so to inform the user, then make these independent `if` statements and perhaps set a flag in each, so to then be able to invoke `error()` once after all tests, if any error(s) occurred.

While these tests can be organized in other ways, having one composite test with multiple regexes cannot really fill the stated need. Each new regex resets most of internal variables, and at any rate one couldn't tell which regex (mis)matched so error reporting wouldn't work.

One can make this work by stringing expressions that assign captures like above but that would lead to code that's easy to advise against<sup>†</sup>--and, since Perl's `&&` (and `and`, etc) operators short-circuit, one could only detect one error that way.

I assume that `&error` refers to a custom sub; if so, then that `&` is probably not needed.

---

<sup>†</sup> This still can only catch one (first tested) error since `or` short-circuits

```
if ( 
    (my $empty_name = $string1 eq '')        or
    (my @bad_namechars = $string1 =~ /.../)  or
    ... 
) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll answer your regex question in a moment, but first go through some thoughts on the particular problem. Since you are just learning, doing toy programs and experiments any way you like is not a problem, but once you get into doing real work, there are some other things can can make your life easier.

I've done this sort of thing with code that goes through a lot of rules without caring about what they are. In this example, `@rules` are a list of code refs. If the rule fails, it returns a defined string describing the violation. Otherwise it returns nothing and we skip it:

```
foreach my $rule ( @rules ) {
    my $problem = $rule->($test_string);
    next unless defined $problem;
    push @problems, $problem;
    }
```

The advantage here is that the meat of the problem doesn't depend on the rules themselves. Add as many rules as you like and this code doesn't change. You don't have to edit this code every time you come up with a new situation you want to check. Instead, you merely add or remove code refs from `@rules`.

So let's make a rule for the allowed characters:

```
my $test_string = 'Smith+';

my @rules = (
    sub { $_[0] =~ m/ \A [a-z] \z/xi ?
        undef : "Names can contain only letters" },
    );

my @problems;
foreach my $rule ( @rules ) {
    my $problem = $rule->($test_string);
    next unless defined $problem;
    push @problems, $problem;
    }

if( @problems ) { print join "\n", @problems }
else { print "No problems" }
```

That outputs:

```
Names can contain only letters
```

And, this approach allows me to give the user a list of all of the problem at once, instead of complaining about one thing for them to fix before they discover the next thing to fix. I'll add another rule. Again, I don't have to change the mechanism that I use to check the rules. I merely add another code ref to the list of code refs to check:

```
my @rules = (
    sub { $_[0] =~ m/ \A [a-z] \z/xi ? undef : "Names can contain only letters" },
    sub { $_[0] =~ m/ \A A-Z /xi ? undef : "Names must start with a capital letter" },
    );
```

Now the output is:

```
Names can contain only letters
Names must start with a capital letter
```

Not that the second rule should be a rule

### Fancier messages

Now, adjust the message and the code ref for anything you like. But, note that this checks that it only has the allowed characters and specifies the general rule. That generally sufficient.

But let's make that error message fancy buy changing the rule to return a fancier message:

```
my @rules = (
    sub {
        my @not_allowed = $_[0] =~ m/ ([^a-z]) /gxi;
        return unless @not_allowed;

        my %chars = map { $_, 1 } @not_allowed;
        my @chars = sort keys %chars;
        "Names can contain only letters. $_[0] also has @chars"
        },
    );
```

I could have golfed this a bit, but I won't. The code ref now starts by matching all of the single characters that aren't the allowed ones. The global match (`\g`) in list context returns all the captures. If there are no captures, the rule was not violated and I return nothing. Otherwise, I do a lot of work to uniq the list of characters and add them to the message. Now the output is:

```
Names can contain only letters. Smith+ also has +
```

Generally I don't think that extra work is worth it.

Comment: Brian, tyvm, I had something else typed out, but I'll make a new question. Your reply was v clever.

Comment: A great system.  And in more complex applications the returned `$problem` can be an object